# Flexible iPhone button

Tags: iphone, ios, button, bitmap

Is there a way to create a flexible iPhone button from a single graphic, like Android does with 9-patch drawables?

For example, would it be possible to use this graphic [image] to create a wider button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Load your image into a UIImage, then use `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` with appropriate parameters to build a copy of the image with hints about the proper end caps. You can then assign this new image to the button.

See [UIImage Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIImage).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look into the [UIImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method `-stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:`

Comment: Props to the Cocoa team for coming up with such wacky names. I'll give it go. Thanks.